# Two-column layout using pure CSS

Tags: html, css

There are blocks named a,b,c,d inside a bigger fixed-width two-column block.

[image: layout]

I want d left to c and below a, it is possible to complete it using pure CSS?

What I have tried,

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted #111;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 178px;
}

#a {
    height: 248px;
}

#b {
    height: 148px;
}

#c {
    height: 198px;
}

#d {
    height: 98px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="a" class="rectangle">a</div>
<div id="b" class="rectangle">b</div>
<div id="c" class="rectangle">c</div>
<div id="d" class="rectangle">d</div>
</div>​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/imom0/E7GYR/1/

To keep it simple, I prefer not to use JavaScript or [masonry](http://desandro.com/resources/jquery-masonry).

Comment: Not without modifying the order of the elements, not really.

Comment: you should know that `display: block-inline;` doesn't exist. `display:inline-block;` Apart from that your question isn't very clear to me.

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: @JamesSouth all except IEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/column-count) CSS property like this:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted #111;
    width: 460px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    column-count:2;
}

.rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 170px; 
}
```

and restructure your HTML to:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="a" class="rectangle">a</div>
<div id="d" class="rectangle">d</div>
<div id="b" class="rectangle">b</div>
<div id="c" class="rectangle">c</div>
</div>
```

`column-count` is supported with the respective vendor prefixes by most browsers. See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn) for more infos.

[An example fiddle can be found here.](http://jsfiddle.net/E7GYR/8/)

Comment: It seems that a,b,c,d are disordered.

Comment: @iMom0 Like I said, you would have to restructure your HTML. In this form, you specify the contents per column. So first all elements in the first column, then in the second and so on ...

Answer (score 3):

Try having the right divs *float* right: http://jsfiddle.net/E7GYR/7/

---

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="a" class="rectangle left">a</div>
<div id="b" class="rectangle right">b</div>
<div id="c" class="rectangle right">c</div>
<div id="d" class="rectangle left">d</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    border: 1px dotted #111;
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
}

.rectangle {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #333;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 178px;
}

.left
{
    float:left;       
}

.right
{
    float:right
}

#a {
    height: 248px;
}

#b {
    height: 148px;
}

#c {
    height: 198px;
}

#d {
    height: 98px;
}
​
```

Comment: Sorry for that I do not explain the fact exactly, the height of a,b,c,d is not determined

Comment: That's going to require knowing in advance where each element is going to fit together, which may or may not be a pain in the ass to handle if its dynamically generated (such as from a database).